# Python Goose cannot extract date

Tags: python, goose

I am using Python Goose. You can find it in [this link](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose)

I want to extract the published date, but when I run the:

```
g = Goose()
entity = g.extract(url="mylink")
date = entity.publish_date
```

I have as a result `None`

I have tried it in many many sites and results were `None`

Any advice?

Comment: Anything accessible at all? Like entity.title?

Comment: entity.title, entity.cleaned_text and entity.canonical_link works perfect!

Comment: Since None is the default value for [publish_date](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose/blob/master/goose/article.py), it looks like somethings going wrong when extracting. Try to dig into the source to check how goose tries to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked the relevant part of the source: [crawler.py](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose/blob/master/goose/crawler.py) 
The publish_date extraction is currently commented out

```
# TODO
# article.publish_date = config.publishDateExtractor.extract(doc)
```

Further examination revealed that if you uncomment the line above, you'll be able to define your custom date extractor. However, there is no default date extractor implemented in Goose. See this method: `set_publishdate_extractor` in https://github.com/grangier/python-goose/blob/master/goose/configuration.py

Comment: oooh. I see. Then it isn't a bug :)...Thank you a lot.

Comment: Is there a generic implementation for date extraction that you could find?

Comment: Date extractor is not implemented in goose until now. Since it is an open source library, you can write that part and send a pull request to the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2014 this feature has been implemented into python-goose in the `extractors/publishdate.py` so `article.publish_date` returns some date. But only if available in the following metadata-fields:

```
rnews:datePublished
article:published_time
OriginalPublicationDate
datePublished
```